# How can I pass ulimit parameters to a Docker with Terraform?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, terraform

I'm trying to setup elasticsearch cluster in Docker with Terraform. Docker compose file containing some ulimit definitions on containers:

```
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
```

But I didn't found any documentation how to do it with Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [terraform docker provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker) does not currently support ulimits. I have created a PR to add support [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/pull/35).

In the meantime, you can install install the branch, by cloning my fork, running `go build && cp terraform-provider-docker $HOME/.terraform.d/plugins/`

You can then pass a `ulimit` block to your container like so

```
provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "elasticsearch" {
  name = "elasticsearch:latest"
}

resource "docker_container" "elasticsearch" {
  image = "${docker_image.elasticsearch.latest}"
  name  = "elasticsearch"

  ports {
    internal = 9200
    external = 9200
  }

  ulimit {
    name = "memlock"
    soft = 100
    hard = 200
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I expected that, but just wanted to be sure.
Also thank you for your efforts with PR!

Comment: How can we pass multiple `ulimit` blocks?